# Win10 shared drives not accessible from other computers on the network

Tags: windows, windows-10, network-shares

Earlier, I was using a Win7HomePremium Desktop, a Win8.1SL laptop (and the shared drives thereon) and a Seagate 2TB NAS drive, all connected to each other through a single ethernet network. I use the NAS drive to backup from both the desktop and the laptop. I then, recently, upgraded my laptop to windows10home. Initially, the network seemed to be working correctly.

Suddenly (I did not change anything - it may be possible that windows updated something on its own), I could not access the win10laptop from the win7hp desktop. But, the NAS drive was accessible from the win7hp desktop. However, I could see the laptop also listed in Network in desktop's FileExplorer.

From the win10h laptop, I could not access the win7hp desktop, or the NAS drive. But, I could see them listed in the Network in laptop's FileExplorer.

In both cases, when I try to map the network drives, I get the message "Name is misspelt ...", etc.

At the same time, I am able to access the WAMP server installed on the win10laptop from the Win7desktop as before.

I have checked all network settings, etc., and they are all correct as before. I have searched the net as well, for a possible solution, but could not find any.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

go into control panel / credential manager and add the login credentials for these devices

Comment: Hi David Johnson, thanks for your answer. I tried several times after adding the credentials of the external devices ... but I always get the message "Check the spelling ... it is incorrect" ... am I missing something more here ? Thanks.